# Data exchanged between two linux servers

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, data-transfer, filebeat

I am Using Filebeat and Kafka for Log management.

I have a query that sends from data Filebeat to Kafka.

How to know if the data is in plaintext format or is it encrypted?

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Filebeat Kafka doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html). By default data is sent plaintext, but [SSL is supported as an option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html#_literal_ssl_literal_3).